# MySQL Trigger to update corresponding column in another table

Tags: mysql, database-design, triggers

I'm trying to write a `MySQL trigger` for a table update (and a similar one for insert) that will take the updated columns and update corresponding columns in another table.

My set-up is this: I have one table (`A`) with several columns of numerical values and a record number `Primary Key`. I have another table (`B`) with identical column names but with short text descriptors that relate to each numerical value and also a record number as a `Foreign Key` referring to table `A`. Both of these tables may grow over time to include more columns - always matching each other - each with a simple predictable name (sticking with integers for now). All records are 1:1.

My hope was that I could write triggers for both `update` and `insert` on table `A` that would look at the numbers and, based on some simple logic, assign a descriptor to the corresponding record in table `B` (inserting that record in the case of the insert trigger). It got rather complicated quickly because I had to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS to identify all current column names in table `A`, check each OLD vs NEW to verify that column was updated (for the `update` trigger anyway), do some logic to determine the appropriate descriptor, then INSERT/UPDATE the corresponding column in table `B`. I can't figure out how to set up a procedure/trigger that doesn't require storing column names in a variable to dynamically build an SQL statement. This is, of course, not allowed in a trigger and I have made some attempts at getting around this by moving the dynamic SQL statement into a separate stored procedure. None of this has worked and I've run into so many roadblocks, I'm coming to the conclusion that I'm going about this in entirely the wrong way.

Since I'm very new to database design, I just don't know what question to ask at this point other than, is there a better way or alternatively, is there a fix to my approach outlined above?

As always, I've searched thoroughly and not found any questions that answer mine but, if you see one that does, please point me that way!

Comment: 2 lines of code >>> 5 paragraphs

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words

Comment: I know... I'd post code but I didn't think it would add to the question. Only make it longer!